# Unable to access hosts beside local host in Ansible

Tags: ansible

I'm self-learning ansible and having the files structure below with my customized `ansible.cfg` and inventory file:

```
---ansible (Folder)   <---Working level
   ---ansible.cfg (Customized cfg)
   ---dev (Inventory File)
   ---playbooks (Folder) <--Issue level
      ---hostname.yml
```

**ansible.cfg**

```
[defaults]
inventory=./dev
```

**dev**

```
[loadbalancer]
lb01

[webserver]
app01
app02

[database]
db01

[control]
control ansible_connection=localansible
```

**hostname.yml**

```
---
  - hosts: all
    tasks:
      - name: get server hostname
        command: hostname
```

My question is when I run `ansible-playbook playbooks/hostname.yml` at `ansible (Folder)` level, everything works fine

```
PLAY [all] *********************************************************************

TASK [setup] *******************************************************************
ok: [control]
ok: [app01]
ok: [db01]
ok: [lb01]
ok: [app02]

TASK [get server hostname] *****************************************************
changed: [db01]
changed: [app01]
changed: [app02]
changed: [lb01]
changed: [control]

PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************
app01                      : ok=2    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=0   
app02                      : ok=2    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=0   
control                    : ok=2    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=0   
db01                       : ok=2    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=0   
lb01                       : ok=2    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=0
```

Howevery when I go into the playbooks folder and run `ansible-playbook hostname.yml` it give me warning saying

```
[WARNING]: provided hosts list is empty, only localhost is available


PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************
```

Is there anything that prevents playbook from accessing the inventory file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ansible does not traverse parent directories in search for the configuration file `ansible.cfg`. If you want to use a custom configuration file, you need to place it in the current directory and run Ansible executables from there or define an environment variable `ANSIBLE_CONFIG` pointing to the file.

In your case: changing the directory to `ansible` and executing is the proper way:

```
ansible-playbook playbooks/hostname.yml
```

I don't know where from you got the idea Ansible would check for the configuration file in the parent directory - the [documentation](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/intro_configuration.html) is unambiguous:

> Changes can be made and used in a configuration file which will be processed in the following order:
>
> - `ANSIBLE_CONFIG` (an environment variable)
> - `ansible.cfg` (in the **current directory**)
> - `.ansible.cfg` (in the home directory)
> - `/etc/ansible/ansible.cfg`

Comment: If I understand correctly, I need to always run the command at the folder level that the cfg file stays at ?

Comment: No, if you want to use a configuration file from the current directory, it needs to be in the current directory. That's quite obvious, I don't understand what might be causing confusion here. If you want to use another configuration file, you need either to use one in the directory Ansible looks for or specify one with an environment variable.

Comment: I was having a little bit confusion. I was assuming ansible will try to check current folder to see if it can find the cfg.If not , it will check the upper level folder until it finds it